# Barcode scanner from web app doesn't return anything

Tags: php, web-applications, barcode, zxing

When clicking on the link on an Android device we can choose to open it in the Barcode Scanner app, but when we scan a barcode it doesn't return anything.

This is our link:

```
<a href="zxing://scan/?ret=<?php echo urlencode("http://172.20.200/projekt/matjakt/Frontend/search.php?s={CODE}"); ?>&SCAN_FORMATS=UPC_A,EAN_13" class="scan">
```

Also when clicking the link on an iPhone, the scanner app opens but just displays a white screen, so we can't scan anything.

Any ideas on what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your return url is invalid. `http://172.20.200` does not make any sense. Either use a domain name or some valid IP. Your IP has three parts. But a valid IP should have four parts.

Comment: Well 127.1 is also localhost.

Comment: You were right, the ip was invalid but the problem is still there. It doesn't return anything.